# Ensuring that items in one listbox does not appear in another listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I am having two listbox controls in my MVC view. The first listbox displays available Users and the second listbox displays selected users. I need to ensure that available users listbox should not contain any matching user in selected list box. Following is the code from my controller that creates IEnumerable collection to bind to the listboxes.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> availableUsers = user.Where(c => c.CompanyId == subscription.CompanyId)
   .Select(c => new SelectListItem
   {
       Value = c.Id.ToString(),
       Text = c.FirstName + " " + c.Surname
   });


IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectedUsers = subscription.Users
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = c.Id.ToString(),
        Text = c.FirstName + " " + c.Surname
    });
```

As mentioned above how do I remove the user from Available user collection that exist in selected users collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe filter the availableUsers list based on whether the user exists in the selectedUsers list. Something like this?

```
var filteredAvailableUsers = availableUsers.Where(u => !selectedUsers.Any(s => s.Value == u.Value));
```

There probably is a more efficient way, but this is what comes to mind off the top of my head.

Comment: I made the assumption that since value was based on the user's Id, that it would be unique. (If I understand the code sample correctly, where it says c.Id, that c is referring to a user, not a company).

Comment: I really don't know what I was thinking but you're absolutely correct. I guess looking at value instead of id threw me off. I'd like to take back my -1 but can't until your answer is edited. Your answer could still be improved by doing something like `availableUsers.Where(u => !selectedUsers.Any(s => u.Value == s.Value))` or `availableUsers.Where(u => selectedUsers.All(s => s.Value != u.Value))`. It would also be most ideal if OP never had to pull the unneeded users in the first place instead of filtering them out.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil, thanks, I edited the answer to use Any instead of FirstOrDefault.